# If $K$ is a splitting field of $x^5-11$ over $\Bbb Q$. Find $Gal(K/\Bbb Q)$ and find all intermediate subfields.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

If $K$ is a splitting field of $x^5-11$ over $\Bbb Q$. Find $Gal(K/\Bbb Q)$ and find all intermediate subfields.

Now $x^5-11$ is irreducibles and splitting field of $x^5-11$ is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]11, a)$ where $a$ is $5$ -th root of unity. Again $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]11, a): \Bbb Q]=20$. I can trace all the $20$ elements but can't see what is $Gal(K/\Bbb Q)$  and all the intermediate fields. So can anyone help me in this if I have not done anything wrong.

Comment: If anyone request I can add the group elements but I have to write a lot then, so I have skipped.

Comment: Have you heard about semidirect preoducts? See http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/semidirect.pdf and take a look at examples 6

Comment: yeah i know semidirect product..

Comment: But what is the group and how to calculate it?

Comment: Up to isomorphism there are only five groups of order $20$, and one can narrow down the possibilities with a little effort. http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_20#The_list

Comment: @Travis  
Which group is isomorphic then this group of galois?

Comment: @user425181 One can check readily that the Galois group is nonabelian and with a little more work that its center is trivial. Among the groups of order $20$ this leaves a single possibility, the Frobenius group of order 20, namely, $\operatorname{Aff}(\Bbb F_5) = \operatorname{GL}(\Bbb F_5) \ltimes \Bbb F_5 \cong \Bbb F_4 \ltimes \Bbb F_5$: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_affine_group:GA(1,5)